# forEach loop to pull element from array & push into new array

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, push

I am trying to have my forEach loop loop through var fruit and push any found strings into arr2.

Here is my code:

```
var fruit = [1,2,3, "apple", "banana", "grape"] 

function isString(fruit) {
var arr2 = []
fruit.forEach(function(element) {
if(element == "string"){
arr2.push(element)
}
return arr2
})

}
```

//desired output is arr2 = "apple", "banana", "grape"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You'll need to use something like `typeof` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to get the type:
`if (typeof element === "string")`

Comment: Try `if(typeof element == "string"){`. Right now you are checking if `1 == "string"`, `2 == "string"`, `3 == "string"`, `"banana" == "string"` so on.. which will be `false`. You are basically wanted to check their type, not the value.

Comment: thank you @ArupRakshit, this helps me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I use this foreach sequence in one of my code...maybe will help you.

string[] Body;

string first = Body.First();          // get content of first index of "Body" array

```
    if (first != "")                // if first index of "Body" array contain data's
    {
      string  Content = "";

        foreach (string line in Content)        // do something
        {
            Content = Content + line + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `typeof` and returns `arr2` at the end of the function `isString`

```js
var fruit = [1,2,3, "apple", "banana", "grape"] 

function isString(fruit) {
  var arr2 = [];
  fruit.forEach(function(element) {
    if(typeof element === "string"){
      arr2.push(element);
    }
  })
  
  return arr2;
}

console.log(isString(fruit))
```

By the way you could use `filter` function to make it shorter

```js
var fruit = [1,2,3, "apple", "banana", "grape"];

var fruitString = fruit.filter(function(element) {
   return typeof element === "string";
});

console.log(fruitString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code, that will work:

```
var fruit = [1,2,3, "apple", "banana", "grape", true, false]; 

function isString(fruit) {
    var arr2 = [];
    fruit.forEach(function(element) {
        if (isNaN(element)) {   // only pushes the strings, not numbers or booleans
            arr2.push(element);
        }
        console.log(arr2);  // output as wished: apple, banana, grape
    })
}
isString(fruit);
```

Comment: hi welcome to SO. Good work and thanks for answering, please consider explaining in an answer what you did and what the inquirer did wrong. People my find answers in search machines, so a little explanation in generall is nice to see

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
  element == "string"
```

With:

```
  typeof element == "string"
```

Because what you're basically doing is comparing the actual data not the type.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You are putting the return within the loop. So it `return` before even the loop completes. That means the first element that is not a string, and it returns and you get an empty array.
2. `element == "string"` is not a correct way to check type. You can use `typeof element === "string"`

There is a third possible issue and that is you actually have to call the function. Find below working code:

```
var fruit = [1, 2, 3, "apple", "banana", "grape"]

function isString(fruit) {
    var arr2 = []
    fruit.forEach(function(element) {
        if (typeof element === "string") {
            arr2.push(element)
        }

    })
    return arr2;

}

isString(fruit);
```